# How to change asp:ListBox1 row background color

Tags: asp.net, background, listbox, background-color, listboxitem

I have an `asp:ListBox1` and two buttons. When I click on button 1, I add a text to `ListBox1`.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Message1");
 }
```

When I click on the second button, another thext is added to `ListBox1`.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Message2");
 }
```

The messages are correctly added. I want to change the background color for each row. For example, I want the row with "Message1" text to have a red background and the other row to have green background. How could I do this?

Comment: By using pure asp.net you can't do that b'cs `ListItem` contains only `Text`as value and it don't have `backColor` property.

Comment: and may there is no control like `ListBoxItem` as u tagged

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper, it's odd to don't be able to change the item's background color. I imagine it should be something basic to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ListItem message1 = new ListItem("Message1","Message1");
    message1.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: RED");
    ListBox1.Items.Add(message1);
 }


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ListItem meassage2 = new ListItem("Message2","Message2");
    message2.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: GREEN");
    ListBox1.Items.Add(message2);
 }
```